# Why can't my video crawler detect a simple video src?

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, web-crawler, scrapy

I am building a web crawler using scrapy, my spider code for detecting and retrieving videos url is:

```
all_links = []

class Onlinecrawl(RobotCrowler):

name = "start"
start_urls = ['https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp',]

#rules to extract the data, if you want more depth go on website and read article about it : https://doc.scrapy.org/en/0.24/topics/link-extractors.html
rules = (
    Rule(LinkExtractor(

        allow=(['https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp']),
        deny=(['/designers', '/edit', '/new-in', '.*\.html']),

        restrict_css=['a'],
        ),
        callback='process_page',
        follow=True,
        ),
)

def parse_page(self, response, starting_url):

    video_details = response.css('video').xpath('@src').extract()
    for video in video_details:
        try:

            all_links.append({"videos": video})
            print (video)


        except (IndexError, TypeError, ValueError) as e:
            self.logger.error(f'Could not add product {product}')
            self.logger.error(str(e))
            # self.increment_dropped_products(starting_url, 1)
            continue
```

I am not getting the simple video with `id=video1` and src `mov_bbb.mp4` . My target is to get any and every single link inside `src` when a `video` tag exists might be on the same level or as a child and not sure where my code fails at it. Plus it is my first spider so feel free to be code critical also kindly note that the website isn't the only one i want to scrap i'm using it for testing but my code should get all srcs when video tag exists.ALso note this is not the full code `__init_subclass__` , `process_page` and `get_rules` functions exist too but the shared code should be enough.

I did go to the shell and type this :

```
scrapy shell 'https://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_video.asp'
```

then:

```
response.xpath("//@src").extract()
```

response :

response.xpath("//@src").extract()

```
['//static.h-bid.com/w3schools.com/20180525/snhb-w3schools.min.js', '//static.h-bid.com/gdpr/cmp.stub.js', 'mov_bbb.mp4', 'mov_bbb.ogg', 'mov_bbb.mp4', 'mov_bbb.ogg', '/images/colorpicker.gif', '/images/w3schoolscom_gray.gif', '/lib/snigel_w3schools_footer.js', 'https://translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit']
```

my wanted src is there but do this code get me every single src? and do i want to use that method ?

Example where even the last shell test fails:

```
scrapy shell 'http://www.aljazeera.net/portal'
```

this is a different website

```
>>> response.xpath("//@src").extract()
['https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?hl=ar', '//players.brightcove.net/665001584001/BJeiBqmye_default/index.min.js', '/Content/js/newPortalScripts?v=Z-iLKM9YBRO-l1eYY_yx1kcRYdw0lCXmuKIN39AaJC41', 'http://www.geoplugin.net/javascript.gp', 'https://d5nxst8fruw4z.cloudfront.net/atrk.gif?account=R69Tk1ao6C525T', '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion.js', '//www.googleadservices.com/pagead/conversion/947178488/?label=O6blCOKKl18Q-JfTwwM&guid=ON&script=0', '//nexus.ensighten.com/aljazeera/arabic/Bootstrap.js', '/Content/images/headerlogo.png', '/File/GetImageCustom/dccdaf9d-a073-4d31-a7b5-b39b468c07cd/530/300', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', '/Views/Shared/shared/images/jazeraLogo 2560 ×1440.png', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/3f749887-1b94-4bdd-b95c-0b739fd4018f/49/49', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/c0257ffc-bed0-4e95-8abe-e3ca0e55fb61/49/49', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/4eee30f8-6bc2-48d5-b615-970be9ba9149/49/49', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/b14f920f-d249-449b-9c7a-450a860a29bf/49/49', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/eb56d7cc-20f1-4e79-be4e-51af09f4cee0/49/49', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/de0bef7f-4a65-486f-9c3e-802d4617e565/49/49', 'http://blogs.aljazeera.net//File/GetImageCustom/43416467-e38c-4967-ba77-88868c13278d/49/49', '/File/GetImageCustom/00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', '/File/GetImageCustom/f4b80a64-7477-48ce-b280-56fd6ddc76d1/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/dccdaf9d-a073-4d31-a7b5-b39b468c07cd/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/1b20fec7-ff09-46d9-bd4c-3c3e17bdb640/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/52ee7757-ab01-46f1-b192-ea572e0d5ef8/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/f254f4e0-f6b2-41c2-9c57-9581dfa57264/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/89fe9d07-626b-4479-a195-0c721a240da1/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/5196299b-257d-40e0-b76f-b9979427eb6f/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/04531520-7ae1-4dec-92fb-6613996bee52/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/290f4cb3-8e81-45c2-893f-30208ec476bf/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/9bee5bfe-635c-4884-934f-c2d481ecba10/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/01c8a89a-2379-4e24-b7b0-a195925324da/272/158', '/File/GetImageCustom/783d5e7b-c34e-4f09-a0fc-1cc903f2af32/272/158', '//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js', '/Content/images/footerlogo.png', '/Content/images/iHorizons-icon.png', '//radar.cedexis.com/1/15249/radar.js']
```

same shell command and it failed to get the src in this block:

```
<video id="main-video-9489741_html5_api" data-video-id="5834567349001" data-account="665001584001" data-player="BJeiBqmye" data-embed="default" class="vjs-tech" tabindex="-1" src="blob:http://www.aljazeera.net/9765540b-1e35-4e8c-a304-9e2f9492a07e"></video>
```

ideally it should return blob:http://www.aljazeera.net/9765540b-1e35-4e8c-a304-9e2f9492a07e

**Edit:**

Another example of the failing case after a comment mentioned the issue was difficult to replicate:

kindly check this link http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/scenarios/2018/9/13/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%83%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AB%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9

and inspect the video in it

You will see 2 great examples of similar issues :

```
<video id="vid-c8d54140-70fe-4561-9780-8a4e7763c58a_html5_api" data-video-id="5834567349001" data-account="665001584001" data-player="BJeiBqmye" data-embed="default" class="vjs-tech" tabindex="-1" poster="http://bc04.ajmn.me/665001584001/201809/2309/665001584001_5834579342001_5834567349001-vs.jpg?pubId=665001584001" src="blob:http://www.aljazeera.net/a071437f-421f-40ac-9dc7-43afb98d96a0"></video>
```

again from this section i'd want blob:http://www.aljazeera.net/a071437f-421f-40ac-9dc7-43afb98d96a0

The second example just under that bloc:

```
<div class="vjs-poster" tabindex="-1" aria-disabled="false" style="background-image: url("http://bc04.ajmn.me/665001584001/201809/2309/665001584001_5834579342001_5834567349001-vs.jpg?pubId=66500158;4001");"></div>
```

I'd also want http://bc04.ajmn.me/665001584001/201809/2309/665001584001_5834579342001_5834567349001-vs.jpg?pubId=66500158;4001 from here .

Comment: It's hard to replicate your issue as the website seems to serve content heavily based on location and time as your blob is not present. However the videos are most likely loaded via javascript and scrapy does not execute any javascript. Try digging around source code for video id with javascript disabled in your browser, it's probably somewhere else than `<video src=`. 
If you need more help you should provide an example we can replicate and output you expect.

Comment: also you should subtitute `response.css('video').xpath('@src').extract()` with `response.xpath("//video/@src").extract()` or `response.css("video::attr(src)").extract()`

Comment: @Granitosaurus i imported selenium and running a headless chrome in middlewares.py so that shouldn't be an issue actually and the way to catch that blob is to inspect the video part around the third way down the page http://www.aljazeera.net/portal

Comment: and can you kindly explain the reason behind your second comment is it to extract from css as well ? if so just wondering do any links actually exist in css ? i just think the classes do and such.

Answer (score 0):

The videos loaded are heavily dependant on javascript and it seems like brightcove.com 3rd party service is used for that.

If you open up network inspector when loading: http://www.aljazeera.net/programs/scenarios/2018/9/13/%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B5%D9%8A%D9%86-%D9%88%D8%A3%D9%81%D8%B1%D9%8A%D9%82%D9%8A%D8%A7-%D8%B4%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%83%D8%A9-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B9%D8%AB%D8%B1%D8%A9-%D8%A3%D9%85-%D9%85%D8%AA%D8%B7%D9%88%D8%B1%D8%A9

[image]

You can see XHR request being made to retrieve some video data in json format. 
It contains image source urls, like:
[image]

To replicate this you need to take a look at the page html source. There's an id used for video:

[image]

Finally you can replicate this easily in scrapy:

```
from scrapy import Spider, Request
import json

class MySpider(Spider):
    name = 'aljazeera'
    start_urls = ["url with video in it"]
    video_api_url = "https://edge.api.brightcove.com/playback/v1/accounts/665001584001/videos/{id}"

    def parse(self, response):
        video_id = response.css('input#MainVideoDM_BCGuid::attr(value)').extract_first()
        url = self.video_api_url.format(id=video_id)
        yield Request(url, self.parse_video)

    def parse_video(self, response):
        data = json.loads(response.body_as_unicode())
        for source in data['sources']:
            yield source
```

Comment: That seems to be a difficult method to scale as in i can't simply just write one code and make it work on other websites and that i have to manually inspect each, is there another approach to just extract the url from the blocks i shared in my question after activating the page using selenium and have that method being scalable which is the most important aspect to me .